# Insert two columns from different tables

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-insert

I need to write an insert query to insert some rows into a table using data from different tables. I have:

- A variable `@ID` which contains ID of the new inserted row in a table. (1)
- A table (2) contains some `ID`s
- A table (3) define the relation between the two above tables.

Now I need to insert for each `ID` in (2) a new row in the table (3).

So if `@ID=2` and IDs = `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`, I want to insert the following rows in Table (3):

```
table1_ID    table2_ID
---------    ---------
1            1
1            2
1            3
1            4
1            5
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? How is this "list" of `IDs` built, and where? Why is the value `6` discarded?

Comment: Or if the "list" is actually just a set from `table2`, how did you identify that these 5 (or 6?) values belong to `ID = 1`? Is it just every row in the table? Please describe the relationship better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the value `6` was not meant to be discarded (if it was, please explain the logic). Also assuming that you just want every row in table 2 inserted into table 2.

```
INSERT dbo.Table3(table1_ID, table2_ID)
  SELECT @ID, ID
    FROM dbo.Table2
    -- WHERE ID <> 6???
  ;
```

---

**If the list of IDs is really a CSV**, then:

First create a Split function ([several alternatives described here, except they output strings instead of integers](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)), e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitInts
(
    @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS @t TABLE(Item INT)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @t(Item) SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter;

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

Now your stored procedure can simply say:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
  @ID INT,
  @IDs VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.Table3(table1_ID, table2_ID)
    SELECT @ID, Item
      FROM dbo.SplitInts(@IDs, ',');
END
GO
```

However if you are on SQL Server 2008 or above, and this list of comma-separated IDs is coming from your application (e.g. from a DataTable or other set), you could use a [Table-Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and avoid the need for splitting.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.SetOfIntegers
( Number INT );
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
  @ID INT,
  @IDs dbo.SetOfIntegers READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.Table3(table1_ID, table2_ID)
    SELECT @ID, Item
      FROM @IDs;
END
GO
```

Then you have to change the C# code to pass your `DataTable` in as `SqlDbType.Structured` instead of passing your CSV in as a string. More info here:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql